# Design Automation (Linking Revit and Plaxis)

Tags: autodesk-forge

Does anyone kow if it is possible to connect in any way Plaxis with Revit through Forge? I think that it can be an interesting option.

Best regards, thanks.

Comment: Very general question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean [Plaxis by Bentley Systems, Inc.](https://www.plaxis.com)?

I am not aware of any such connection.

What exactly do you have in mind?